# Debug problems with ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project that I created in Visual Studios 2012. When I debug it, a new page opens up in my browser, but it just keeps loading. Nothing every displays. When I stop debugging, the project finally loads. However, I can't post anything to it. If I do, I'm given an error. Is this normal?

Comment: do you have a breakpoint set that it's hitting?  Go to Debug -> Delete all breakpoints and then debug.  See if the page loads.

Comment: Does the problem persist with every MVC project?